# Increment Decrement In React without using state or this

Tags: reactjs, state, this, innerhtml

[XML layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ys0A.png)

I wanted to create something similar to

```
    function up() {
        count++;
        document.querySelector(.up).innerHTML = count;
     }
```

In react without state or 'this'. Is it possible? if so, then how?

Comment: Why not use state? It seems a good use for this kind of thing.

Comment: I mean if you're wanting to write this in vanilla JS vs utilize a framework... you're welcome to do that.. why use React in the first place if you want to do this? there can be some use cases but those are pretty rare. But you could make a global variable that you continue to update on some interval and write to the document

Answer (score 1):

You should use state here and not try to manually update the DOM. This is what React is good at doing and you should try to utilize this framework better. I would recommend reviewing some tutorials on React specifically around `state` and `props`... what they are and how each is used.

That being said a way to write this component out with state would be

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function UpDown() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)  

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="count">{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Up</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>Down</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Breaking this down into smaller easier to understand bits...

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
```

here we are defining a variable called `count` that stores the current count value, we also define a setter variable called `setCount` to help us update that count value. 
 The `0` passed through to `useState` is the default value.. telling the state to start out at 0.

```
<h1 className="count">{count}</h1>
```

Here we are referencing the count variable when rendering the component, this will display the value of `count` on the page.

```
<button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Up</button>
```

Here we are defining the behavior of the click event on each button. The logic for the Up button is to increase the number by 1 on each button click. This will trigger the component to render again when the state value changes.. resulting in the component displaying the new count.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to define an event handler somewhere inside the functional component and then you need to assign it to the onClick property of the button element. So your code should be like that:

```js
export default function UpDown() {
  function up() {
    document.querySelector(".count").innerText =
      parseInt(document.querySelector(".count").innerText) + 1;
  }

  return (
    // ...
    <h1 className="count">0</h1>
    <button className="up" onClick={up}>
      Up
    </button>
    // ...
  );
}
```

Although this is a working code, it is not the right way to use React. If you use React, you should (even must) use states and/or props because they are React's core; they are why people use React and they are the way using React.